# how to make navigation bar slide from right slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```js
function openNav() {
     document.getElementsByClassName("menu-overlay").style.width = "50%";
}
function closeNav() {
     document.getElementsByClassName("menu-overlay").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
.menu-overlay {
 display: none;
 top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0%;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 right: 0;
 background-color: #ef4f50;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu-body{
 position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
 background-color: #ef4f51;
 width: 35%;
 float: right;
}

span.closer {
    font-size: 50px;
    float: right;
    color: white;
    padding: 30px;
}

.menu-pan{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 80px;
}
.menu-pan li {
 padding: 10px 0;
}
.menu-pan li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simple-line-icons/2.4.1/css/simple-line-icons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
      <div class="header-top clearfix">
        <a href="https://www.google.co.in/" target="_blank" class="pull-right btn btn-danger btn-round">DONATE NOW</a>
        <a class="l-right toggle-menu" href="#" onclick="openNav()">
          <span class="icon-menu"></span>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="menu-overlay">
        <div class="menu-body">
          <a href="#"><span class="closer"><i class="icon-close icons" onclick="closeNav()"></i></span></a>
          <ul class="menu-pan">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Our Purpose</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
```

hello this is my menu bar code.i want my navigation bar to be open when i click on the hamburger icon from right side with transition (smooth) effect with width 50% & remaining part will be overlay.
"https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_overlay" this link has the same effect but from left right.

Comment: Where is the `#mySidenav` element?

Comment: do u have your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: sorry i just mixed up my previous code.i have updated code now. i want to open "menu-overlay" class

Comment: where are you calling the `openNav()` function? I can see 2 `closeNav()` but not a single `openNav()`

Comment: i have updated my code

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` function returns an array so using `getElementsByClassName("menu-overlay").style` would be incorrect. Instead use it like so:

```
function openNav() {
     document.getElementsByClassName("menu-overlay")[0].style.width = "50%";
}
function closeNav() {
     document.getElementsByClassName("menu-overlay")[0].style.width = "0";
}
```